# Access Files in Remote server using console applcation in C#

Tags: c#

How to Access Files in Remote server using remote server credentials with console applcation in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Use [sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) to connect to your remote server